# Extra space between the dot of extension and the file name

Tags: batch-file

I use the following code in Windows batch to generate file's names suffixed with the date and time.:

```
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/:/ " %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a-%%b-%%c)
set mytime=%mytime: =%
```

When I try to generate a file name like: `ECHO DATABASE_2014-05-01_04-38-PM` every thing works fine.
However, when I try to add kind of extension to the file name such as `.sql`:

```
ECHO DATABASE_%mydate%_%mytime%.sql
```

I have got output like this: `DATABASE_2014-05-01_04-31-PM .sql` in-which an extra blank space is found between `.sql` and `PM` in the last of the file name.

How could I fix this issue to make the extension directly attached to the file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set "mytime=%mytime: =%"
```

You have an aditional space at the end of the line. Quoting the assignment of the variable prevents this problem